# How implement a basic wait for a specific file to be closed from write mode under windows?

Tags: bash, cygwin, file-handling

I have a bash script run under Windows and I do want to wait until a specific file is not open for write anymore.

Does anyone know a way to implement this in bash under cygwin, without installing other utilities (`lsof` is not available by default).

Comment: May I ask why you want it in Bash in the first place? Bash is weak and not cross-platform script system. From my experience, Python, is much better alternative for writing routine scripts.

Comment: I agree with you, still writing daemon controlling scripts in Python is not what I am looking for right now.